# Wordpress - Calling on Posts From Different Categories Through a Slider

Tags: php, wordpress, slider, posts

Hope someone can help me, I've been struggling for days on this trying to find the answer...

Basically, I have a wordpress site that has a slider (not a plug-in just open source code) which is called to using a 'get_template' but it displays the same three posts on every single page. I have different posts in different categories and want the slider to correspond on each separate page and echo the posts from each particular category.

---

```
<div id="slidorion">
<div id="slider">

<?php
query_posts( 'posts_per_page=3' );
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="slide">"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

</div>

<div id="accordion">

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="link-header"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
<div class="link-content">

<?php the_excerpt(); ?>

</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

</div>
</div>
```

---

here is a link to the site if you need to see it to totally understand what I mean and need to do...

http://www.kaijocreative.co.uk/footballnatter

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should alter your query adding `cat` or `category`  to your `query_posts( 'posts_per_page=3' );` according to what you exactly want

see [Query_posts ()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts#Example_1)  and also have a look at [WP_Query class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use find out the category ids from each post, then use these ids in the

$category = get_the_category();

$post_catid= $category[0]->term_id;

$querystr='cat='.$post_catid.'&posts_per_page=3';

query_posts($querystr);